# Android: control behaviour of homescreen rotation

Tags: android, rotation, widget, homescreen

Is there any way I can achieve the desired behaviour on rotation of the device, as illustrated in the following sketch (the wavy thing is a widget).  Most likely this is something that would be controlled by the launcher, rather than controlled programmatically from any one app -- if so, is there any launcher that allows this?

Basically the reason I'm asking is because I want the *widget* to behave as illustrated (the widget is what I'm coding), even when the user's device is set to rotate the home screen on device rotation.  Basically the only way I can see this working is if the grid layout is fixed relative to the physical screen, with the app icons just rotating within their box, and the widgets either updating their content for the new layout, or just keeping the previous content (so that the content rotates with the screen).

For updating of widget content, is there any way of detecting screen home screen rotation programmatically (different to screen rotation, since the home screen may not rotate)?  This is relevant to me even for the "what I get" scenario, because the aspect ratio of the widget seems to change when the home screen is rotated, and I need to detect this and update the widget content to fit better.

[image: Behaviour of homescreen on rotation]

dfdd

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
1. layout-sw480dp
2. layout-sw600dp
3. layout-sw720dp
```

Answer (score 0):

You are unlikely to find a solution for this as the home screen (launcher) varies wildly in implementation.  Many launchers don't support landscape orientation, and expecting the launcher to accommodate a widget which can expand in two different directions is simply asking too much of them.

For the launchers which do support landscape orientation, the widget should be repositioned for free without effort on your part.  You may wish to detect which orientation the widget is in (such as via `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`) when your provider is choosing a layout, setting up views etc, but that's about it.